# How to connect to JMX agent using python

Tags: java, python, django, jmx

I am working on custom monitoring system to my server.

the application is developed using python and Django.

The server is running java web applications and I need to monitor the JVM under which the application server is running, so I start the applications with enable the JMX.

Now I need to connect my python application to the JVM JMX agent.

Is there any way to get that?

I have read about the HtmlAdapterServer, that enable managing JMX MBeans from specific url but I do not know how can I use it?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 4):

How about using Jython ? http://www.jython.org/

Answer (score 2):

There is a reference implementation of a [WebServices based JMXServer](https://ws-jmx-connector.dev.java.net/) you can deploy on your server. Based on the docs, it is possible to use VB Scripting to invoke JMX operations, so I would assume you could use Python too.

Update:

[Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/) provides an HTTP/REST API to access JMX MBeanServers. This should be easily invoked by a python client.

Comment: Thanks, but java.net is now closed. The page has been archived, but without the attachments: https://web.archive.org/web/20120205021705/http://ws-jmx-connector.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

Jpype is another option. Start jvm and code java to retrieve glassfish monitoring data. http://jpype.sourceforge.net/

Comment: New website: https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype