# How to read a JMX MBean attribute using Ansible?

Tags: java, ansible, jvm, jmx

I use an Ansible playbook to start my JVM application and want to have a health-check task to ensure the application is running. That application has no HTTP interface but exposes several attributes via MBeans. So can I get access to those attributes from Ansible?

Comment: How would you get access to those attributes without ansible ?

Comment: Unless there is not already an Ansible module available, one would need to create one in Python, see [How to connect to JMX agent using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491082/). Since that seems to be not a quick and easy task, create an Ansible Custom Module in Java might be easier, or use an other script as wrapper. Overall it possible to achieve.

Comment: You could start with a research on [jmxQuery to monitor Java via Python](https://davidgildeh.com/2018/03/14/introducing-jmxquery-to-monitor-java-via-python/) and also search further for `jmx-exporter`, `prometheus jmx`. Please take note that just looking for tools, libraries, modules, further documentation, etc. is not on-topic here ...

Comment: An other approach could be to something like [`ansible-javax`](https://github.com/tima/ansible-javax) "_A module for executing an arbitrary java class or jar in a cleaner, more Ansible-like way._". Slowly it turns out and because of the many possibilities to achieve your goal, you would probably need to define before how do you like to access the JMX interface and make a design and decission upfront.